# Granting windows service file access

Tags: windows-10, openssh, icacls

I'm attempting to run a connection with openssh by using a service. Unfortunately, openssh requires that the authentication key is readable only by the one user who intends to well..use it (If there's a way to make it skip that check, I haven't found it). This works fine with normal users, using:

```
icacls .\private.key /inheritance:r
icacls .\private.key /grant:r "%username%":"(R)"
```

Windows services runs their own semi-user, and I am completely incapable of giving that user the correct file authority.

edit: If anyone have any good ideas for other either opensource or free to use ssh programs or libraries that can be used to create tunnels with authentication keys, I'm all ears. Seems a lot of them have trouble supporting windows properly.

Comment: Howdy!  Which account is your Service currently set to run as?  What have you already tried to grant that account permission to read that file, and what was the result?  Regarding your edit: we won't be recommending software, as that's off-topic for SU.

Comment: On the service properties "Log On" tab, you can change which user the service runs as. or did you try: icacls ./test.txt /grant:r "SYSTEM":"(R)"

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It's set to run as "local system". Since the service is created programmatically on a variety of computers, I will not be able to choose which user it runs as

Comment: @GarrGodfrey At first glance it seems to work, as it's not giving out any immediate errors, but the actual ssh connection isn't working for some reason. I will continue to play around to see if I can get any additional errors out (or, better, make it work). It does seem like a really simple solution if this was all that was needed.

Comment: SYSTEM is the user name for the "Local System".  But a service that isn't set to work interactively has other limitations.

Comment: I got it to work! @GarrGodfrey solution worked perfectly! Thanks a lot. And thanks for the explanation. I wasn't aware this is how it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer so it can be found easier (originally in comments).

The default user name windows services run under is simply, "SYSTEM".  Thus, the command line method to set permissions:

```
icacls .\private.key /inheritance:r
icacls .\private.key /grant:r "SYSTEM":"(R)"
```